# Ionic SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I get this error after I run `ionic` in command prompt, and the problem persists until I remove `~/.ionic/config.json`, but a while later it begins to show this error message again.
how do I really get rid of this?
(Windows 10 user)

this is the content of config.json:

```
{
  "lastCommand": "2017-06-21T14:57:29.860Z",
  "urls": {
    "api": "https://api.ionic.io",
    "dash": "https://apps.ionic.io"
  },
  "user": {},
  "tokens": {
    "appUser": {},
    "telemetry": "501f31d8-48d1-4cd0-9919-68ccb7b1e30a"
  },
  "cliFlags": {
    "confirm": false,
    "interactive": true,
    "telemetry": true,
    "yarn": false
  }
}
```

I realized that only `"lastCommand"` is changed during every execution of `ionic` and overall, I've monitored it through `git` and reverted back to the last working config file that wasn't helpful.

the content of ionic.config.json:

```
{
  "name": "restaurant",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular"
}
```

Comment: could you please add the content of your `ionic.config.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

Open your config file in Notepad++ and check the encoding format. The encoding format should be UTF-8 and nothing else, not even UTF-8 BOM. If it is, change it to UTF-8. save file and try running it again. Hope it helps. This mostly happen when you edit json files in notepad.

Note: DO NOT USE Notepad to do the above steps, as notepad considers UTF_8 and UTF-8-BOM as same.